# Empty result from rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I want to create a service in order to populate dropdown from database. I tried this:

Merchant Class:

```
export class Merchant {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Merchant Service:

```
 getList(): Observable<Merchant> {
    return this.http.get<Merchant>(environment.api.urls.merchants.base, {});
  }
```

SQL query:

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

Working example:

```
    @GetMapping("/list")
public Iterable<Merchants> getMerchantsList() {
    return merchantRepository
            .findAll();
}
```

I tried this:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<?> getMerchantsList() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(merchantRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
}
```

I want to use mapper before I send the response. Currently the list in Angular is empty. Probably I should return `Iterable<Merchants>` not `ResponseEntity<MerchantDTO>`?

I use Java 10.

Comment: Your rest serice return an Iterable of merchants. Your angular service returns an Observable emitting a single merchant. That doesn't match. You need an array to populate a dropdon, don't you?

Comment: Yes, How I can implement this?

Comment: Well, by changing the type to Array<Merchant>. Also, why does your getMerchantsList() method return void instead of... a merchants list? Why does it use findFirst()? You want to return all the merchants, not just the first one. You want collect(Collectors.toList()), not findFirst().orElseGet(). And you want to return that list, not ignore it.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. Post is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems, on both sides. Let's start by the server-side. You want to return a *list* of merchants to populate a dropdown *list*, so you correctly named your method getMerchants*List*(). But instead of returning a *list* as its name indicates, it returns `void`. `void` is nothing, nada, hence the empty response.

So you need to return a `List<Merchant>`, or, if you really want to (but it's unnecessary here since you don't want to set anything other than the response body), a `ResponseEntity<List<Merchant>>`. Calling `findFirst()` is counter-productive. You don't want the first merchant of the list. You want the whole list:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public List<MerchantDTO> getMerchantsList() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(merchantRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<List<MerchantDTO>> getMerchantsList() {
    List<MerchantDTO> list = StreamSupport.stream(merchantRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
}
```

Note that the code would be simpler if your findAll() method returned a List instead of an Iterable. You could just use `findAll().stream()` to get a stream.

At the client-side, you're doing the same mistake. You want the response body to be an *array* of merchants, to populate the dropdown *list*. But you're using an `Observable<Merchant>`. You need an `Observable<Array<Merchant>>`. And passing an empty options object to `get()` is useless:

```
getList(): Observable<Array<Merchant>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Merchant>>(environment.api.urls.merchants.base);
}
```

Finally, you're lying to yourself by creating a class. HttpClient will never create an instance of your class. It doesn't know about it, and simply parsed the JSON it receives to plain old JavaScript objects. So you should really define an interface, not a class:

```
export interface Merchant {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  state_raw: string;
  users: string;
}
```

You should really use Spring-data-jpa, too. It would simplify your repositories a lot.